# Dash error : 'dash_core_components' has no attribute 'send dataframe'

Tags: python, plotly-dash

In my dash I have a callback that create a `pd.to_dict` object that is stored with `dcc.Store`, in order to be used for further plots.

I am trying to create a download button to download this created data frame.

This is part of my code (removed other import or layout options) :

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
        html.H2('Enter a text query'),
        dcc.Store(id='memory'),
        html.Button('Submit', id='button', n_clicks=0),
        html.Button("Download CSV", id="csv"),
        dcc.Download(id="download-df")])

@app.callback(
    Output('memory', 'data'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('searchterm', 'value')]

)

def create_df_func(n_clicks, searchterm):
    #some code to create df
        return df.to_dict(orient='records')


@app.callback(
    Output('download-df', 'data'),
    [Input('csv', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('memory', 'data')],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def download_csv(n_clicks, df):
    data = pd.DataFrame(df)
    return dcc.send_data_frame(data.to_csv, "mydf.csv")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

But when running the app.py, I get `'dash_core_components' has no attribute 'send dataframe'`, even though it has it.

I have dash version 2.0.0.

Comment: You haven't specifically imported `send_data_frame`, so you should be using `dcc.send_data_frame`.

Comment: I’ve mistakenly pasted the wrong version of my code. I’ve edited it. I in fact already use ‘dcc.send_data_frame’ (and PyCharm suggest ‘send_data_frame’ when I start typing it), so I don’t understand the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have dash version 2.0.0

Replace how you import dash core components from this

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
```

to this

```
from dash import dcc
```

> As of Dash 2, the development of dash-core-components has been moved to the main Dash repo

[quote source](https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components)

Comment: Thank you, but now I have this issue when clicking the download button : `Error: Failed component prop type: Invalid component prop `data` key `mime_type` supplied to Download.

Bad object: {

  "content": "IiINCg==",

  "filename": "mydf.csv",

  "mime_type": null,

  "base64": true

}

Valid keys: [

  "filename",

  "content",

  "base64",

  "type"

]`

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that one. Can you share the value of `data`?

Comment: It's all good, there was another missing "dcc." in my code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help. `html` should also by imported from `dash` by the way.

Comment: Yes, I've changed it all. thanks